# Passing an array of numbers to a recursive Java program

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I am writting a program that displays m(i) for i = 1,2,3,4,5,107,1060. The result should be a double value. Whereas the series is m(i) = 1/2 + 2/3 +.....i/i+1

I am trying to pass the required numbers by using an array. But I'm getting a compatibility problem. So far I have this:

```
public class Recursive {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] s;
        s = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,107,1060};

        System.out.println(""   ,m(s));
    }

    public static double m(int i){
        double result;
        if(i > 1){
            result = i/(i + 1) + m(i - 1);
        } else{
            result = i/(i + 1);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: `m` requires an `int` (one value) you are offering a `int[]` (the whole array). A loop to call `m` for each value in the array (`m[i]`) should do the job.

Comment: can anyone make me understand what is the my mistake

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger That should be an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to pass the array as an argument to the method `m()`, 
or you could have the array declared at the class level to avoid the recursion overhead. 
 For this small array let's take the 1st approach.
Then, inside `m()` you made a logical mistake that you must fix. 
You need to sum `s[i]/s[i] + 1` and not `i / (i + 1)`.
Also the condition in the `if` statement from `i > 1` to `i > 0` because the indexes of an array are `0` based:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] s = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 107, 1060};
    System.out.println(m(s, 6));
}

public static double m(int[] s, int i){
    double result;
    if(i > 0){
        result = 1.0 * s[i]/(s[i] + 1) + m(s, i - 1);
    } else{
        result = 1.0 * s[i]/(s[i] + 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The factor `1.0` that is multiplied is needed to avoid the integer division:

```
s[i]/(s[i] + 1)
```

which would always result to `0`

Comment: Meaning? It does produce the sum you want, doesn't it?

Comment: As the sequence should be 1/2 + 2/3 + 3/4 + 4/5+ 5/6 + 107/108+ 1060/1061

Comment: Okay! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments you received, most folks think your question is asking for:

```
public class Recursive {

    public static double m(int i) {
        double result = i / (i + 1.0);

        if (i > 1) {
            result += m(i - 1);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] s = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 107, 1060};

        for (int i : s) { 
            System.out.println("m(" + i + ") = " + m(i));
        }
    }
}
```

> As the sequence should be 1/2 + 2/3 + 3/4 + 4/5+ 5/6 + 107/108+
>   1060/1061

This clarifies that you're really asking for:

```
public class Recursive {

    public static double m(int i, int[] s) {
        double result = s[i] / (s[i] + 1.0);

        if (i > 0) {
            result += m(i - 1, s);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] s = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 107, 1060};

        System.out.println(m(s.length - 1, s));
    }
}
```

Which works except when `s` is an empty array -- just like the other potential answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The method `m()` needs an argument which is an `int` but you are passing the whole array. Keep a for loop and pass the `m()` for every element or handle the logic in the `m()`

Comment: Oh, it seems some one answered via comments